# Proguard fails with firebase FCM

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, android-proguard

HI I am using Google Firebase Cloud Messaging in my application just now.

Prior to using FCM I was able to generate release apk with `buildToolsVersion 23.0.2`

as I have updated `buildToolsVersion 25.0.2` and added few firebase dependencies, I am suddenly getting exception:

```
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease (Thread[Task worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 4.354 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Is there anything I need add to `proguard.txt` for firebase?

My Firebase dependencies are as follows:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
```

Also I am using **Custom Parse SDK** reference from here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/tree/master/Parse, I am adding parse sdk as **external project** with little modification in src code according to my needs.

Comment: It sounds like you changed several different things, then noticed a problem.  Can you narrow it down to the *single* change that caused the problem?  None of us can really do that.

Comment: did you figure out the solution?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?